# Enter File in a File Input

Tags: nightmare

With `nightmarejs` how to enter a file in a file input and confirm it?

It's for automation of an attachment (e.g. in email). The file input I mean is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of to do uploads with Nightmare is to use the [debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol).  This is how [`nightmare-upload`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-upload) works, you might want to give that a try.